# is there any way i can have ip rotation for email server

Tags: email, postfix, iptables

Greetings,

I am starting the mass email business but my ip's are blacklisted. is there any way anybody can help me with ip rotation implementation. or any other source which will help me in mantaining whitelist of ip's.

Comment: Why are you blacklisted?  I'd tackle that one first.  There are legitimate mass email businesses (supporting people with large opt in newsletters for example).  Doing that wrong can get you blacklisted.  So figure out how to do it right, unless you set out to do it wrong in which case you ain't getting my help either.

Comment: If you've been blacklisted and it's inhibiting your ability to send out UCE, then *thank god for blacklisting*.

Comment: @Chopper3 There are plenty of mass email companies that operate legally (and morally), in the interest of both their clients and their users. You assume they want to spam and that's a bit unprofessional for a moderator, don't you think?

Comment: The assumption comes from the requirement to constantly dodge blacklisting, not something a professional email company has a need to do.

Comment: @Oli - Systems Administrators who spend an inordinate amount of their time combatting spam, tend to err on the side of "If it remotely smells like spam, then it is spam".

Comment: @GregD @Chopper3 As somebody who maintains a newsletter and a mailing list, I know how easy it is to end up on a blacklist even with legitimate mail. There are infinitely more productive, positive and helpful comments you could have made rather than just implicitly slandering the guy. @dunxd's example is the one you should follow next time. If you're not here to help, or to ask for help, you shouldn't be here.

Comment: @Oli - I am here to help and have in the past.  What I'm not here to do is help people devise ways of bypassing security or to send out spam.  I'm not going to take responsibility for the way that @user63969 (who just registered today, who posted this one question) worded his or her own question.  If it's not obvious to the OP that we think they're trying to spam people (especially in light of the fact that s/he can't be bothered to come back as of yet) then I can't help them.

Comment: @Oli - And I don't think you're clear on the definition of slander...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, please list all IPs you have access to so we can blacklist them all. Thank you!

Ok, that might have been in jest. But, you're asking the people who are blacklisting you. Over time it wont matter how many IPs you use, if you're sending unsolicited bulk mail, "the system" will adapt and blacklist you again.

If you are seriously in the business of sending solicited mail, I would concentrate on getting those IPs unlisted (which is not hard if you're only sending solicited mail). There's basically no way you're ever getting on a whitelist; it just doesn't happen for bulk email companies.